# Arduino UNO + USB Host Shield 2.0 + RFID RFC522

Tags: arduino-uno, usb

I'm trying to get done following. Connect a Keyboard over USB -> USB Host Shield -> Grab the pushed key (char) from the keyboard and write them to the rfid writer.

So the code for the rfid writer is done, and works well - but only over the serial monitor (osx) / putty(win10).
Watt also works is the USBHIDbootKbd from the examples of the USB_Host_Shield_Library_2.0.

So was I exactly need is grab the key'(s) from the keyboard until e.g. '/', store them into a buffer and send / write it to the code line of the rfid writer.
First line for input is where comment:  // Ask personal data: Password
and second  // Ask personal data: user name.

attached is the code for the rfid writer

Thanks in advice
Cheers

```
    /*
 * Write personal data of a MIFARE RFID card using a RFID-RC522 reader
 * Uses MFRC522 - Library to use ARDUINO RFID MODULE KIT 13.56 MHZ WITH TAGS SPI W AND R BY COOQROBOT. 
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *             MFRC522      Arduino       Arduino   Arduino    Arduino          Arduino
 *             Reader/PCD   Uno/101       Mega      Nano v3    Leonardo/Micro   Pro Micro
 * Signal      Pin          Pin           Pin       Pin        Pin              Pin
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * RST/Reset   RST          9             5         D9         RESET/ICSP-5     RST
 * SPI SS      SDA(SS)      10            53        D10        10               10
 * SPI MOSI    MOSI         11 / ICSP-4   51        D11        ICSP-4           16
 * SPI MISO    MISO         12 / ICSP-1   50        D12        ICSP-1           14
 * SPI SCK     SCK          13 / ICSP-3   52        D13        ICSP-3           15
 *
 * Hardware required:
 * Arduino
 * PCD (Proximity Coupling Device): NXP MFRC522 Contactless Reader IC
 * PICC (Proximity Integrated Circuit Card): A card or tag using the ISO 14443A interface, eg Mifare or NTAG203.
 * The reader can be found on eBay for around 5 dollars. Search for "mf-rc522" on ebay.com. 
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         5           // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          6          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);        // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  SPI.begin();               // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();        // Init MFRC522 card
  Serial.println(F("Write personal data on a MIFARE PICC "));
}

void loop() {

  // Prepare key - all keys are set to FFFFFFFFFFFFh at chip delivery from the factory.
  MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;

  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
    return;
  }

  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    return;
  }

  Serial.print(F("Card UID:"));    //Dump UID
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
  }
  Serial.print(F(" PICC type: "));   // Dump PICC type
  MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = mfrc522.PICC_GetType(mfrc522.uid.sak);
  Serial.println(mfrc522.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));

  byte buffer[34];
  byte block;
  MFRC522::StatusCode status;
  byte len;

  Serial.setTimeout(20000L) ;     // wait until 20 seconds for input from serial
  // Ask personal data: Password
  Serial.println(F("Type your Password, ending with #"));
  len = Serial.readBytesUntil('#', (char *) buffer, 30) ; // read family name from serial
  for (byte i = len; i < 30; i++) buffer[i] = ' ';     // pad with spaces

  block = 1;
  //Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else Serial.println(F("PCD_Authenticate() success: "));

  // Write block
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, buffer, 16);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Write() success: "));

  block = 2;
  //Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  // Write block
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, &buffer[16], 16);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Write() success: "));

  // Ask personal data: User Name
  Serial.println(F("Type your User Name, ending with #"));
  len = Serial.readBytesUntil('#', (char *) buffer, 20) ; // read first name from serial
  for (byte i = len; i < 20; i++) buffer[i] = ' ';     // pad with spaces

  block = 4;
  //Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  // Write block
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, buffer, 16);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Write() success: "));

  block = 5;
  //Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }

  // Write block
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Write(block, &buffer[16], 16);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Write() failed: "));
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  else Serial.println(F("MIFARE_Write() success: "));


  Serial.println(" ");
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA(); // Halt PICC
  mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();  // Stop encryption on PCD

}
```

Comment: what is your question? ... you said nothing about any problem

Comment: i'm not able to store / use the input from the keyboard and write them into the query from the rfid code. The rfid code waiting for an input from the Serial monitor. So o need to change that is it waiting for the input from the keyboard